# Recursing over a List: why base case is Nil, not List(Nil)

Tags: scala

I'm trying to recurse over a list like this (which works):

```
def sumList(lst: List[Int]): Int = lst match {
  case Nil       => 0
  case n :: rest => n + sumList(rest)
}
```

However, I don't understand why base case is `Nil`, not `List(Nil)`.

(I've seen in some answers that `Nil` represents empty list but:

```
scala> List(Nil) == Nil
val res0: Boolean = false
```

)

Comment: I am confused. Why would you expect a nested list which contains the empty list (and is thus clearly not empty) to be equal to the empty list? How can a list which contains one element (regardless of what that element is) be equal to a list which contains zero elements?

Comment: You're right. I've come to the same conclusion after checking `List() == Nil`

Comment: If you look at the definition of `List` you will see that it is pretty obvious that it could be either a cons `::` with a head and a tail, or a `Nil` which is the empty list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Nil` does not represent a missing value or `null`, it is a value that represents an empty list. It can equivalently be expressed `List()`. `List(Nil)` is a list that contains an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

```
val x = List()
val y = Nil
println(x == y) //true
```

In some cases, you must write the type (e.g., Nil: List[Int]) when writing Nil.

Comment: As a stylistic matter, I always recommend `List.empty[Int]` rather than `Nil: List[Int]` when needed for type inference.